# jquery filedownload not able to download

Tags: jquery

I am trying to implement jquery filedownload in my code but it is not working as expected i am using local system as my file system to download file can somebody help me on this i am new to jquery or rather provide with an working code.

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

```
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function () {
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
        preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
        failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
    });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
});


</script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="E://Download/Anshuman.txt" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience">Download</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error msg on console ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="E://Download/Anshuman.txt" class="fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience">Download</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadSimpleRichExperience", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = $(this).attr('href');
hiddenElement.download = 'aaa.csv';
hiddenElement.click();

});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jun 17, 2017 11:52:44 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Filedownload' did not find a matching property.
Jun 17, 2017 11:52:44 AM

Comment: still it is not working @Riaz Laskar i have posted the error i am getting.

Comment: Hi anybody have jquery $.filedownload with struts2 implementation working code ??

Comment: now with your code download is happening but with a message failed network error. Kindly look into this

Comment: r u running it on a server??

Comment: if ur on a server instead of a path `E://Download/Anshuman.txt` try it with a url `http://localhost/Anshuman.txt`

Comment: Yeah I was running it on tomcat apache server.